# hedging with a 3 month fx forward every month

Tags: fx, forward

I think this is a bit odd question. Let us say I want to hedge my fx exposure every month but using 3 month forwards . How can I do that ? Is it not easy just to use 1 month forwards ? I recalculate my expsoure every month. In other words let us say I am us investor but I get my profits from a euro company. So every month I calcuate the expected return I might get the next month and do the hedge accordingly. This is straight forward with a one month forward but assuming there exists only 3 month forward contracts in the market(hypothetical) how can one do the hedging ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good question... clearly you've read [using 3 month forwards](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8234/why-using-3-months-forward-to-hedge-fx-risk-on-a-fund-of-funds-portfolio) and see they are more liquid than other FX forward instruments.

I guess that if there were only 3 month forward contracts in the market then by buying and selling the 3 months for different maturities, you could structure a set of 1 month forwards.

so from today 21st Aug to hedge a short position:

- buy 3 month for 21st Nov
- wait 1 month until 21st Sep
- On 21st Sep sell 3 month for 21st Dec

You've covered 1 month from 21st Aug to 21st Sep.

But there's a tail position to cover from 21st Nov to 21st Dec. Maybe someone else can do better there.